# header location with variables

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I have a php file that finds a product_id from another id, called id_4d. I would like to make a redirection, as soon as we put the id_4d in the search bar, the header location fills with the id_product (done) but we also need to include the name of the product in the search bar with a dash between each word (to get to the right page), anyone have an idea? Thank you a lot

```
?>
    <form action="p.php" method="GET">
        <input name="4d">
    </form>

            <p class="card-text"><b>ID 4d</b> : <?php echo $_GET['4d']; ?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><b>Id_product</b> :
                <?php
                $id_4d = $_GET['4d'];

                $db = \Db::getInstance();
                $request = 'SELECT `id_product`  FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` WHERE `id_4d` = '.$id_4d.' ';
                $id = $db->executeS($request);
                $prod = new Product($id);
                
                if(empty($id))
                {
                    echo 'Le produit demandé n\'existe pas';
                } else{
                    echo ($id[0]['id_product']);
                }

                ?></p>
        </div>
<?php
   
    $page = $id[0]['id_product'];
```

I got this header for now :

```
header("location:/website/www/fr/$page.html");
```

But the URL must be this type :

website/www/fr/'id_product'-here-is-the-name-of-the-product.html

The real problem is I got a big database and I don't know where the name is lol

Comment: The real problem here is sql injection...

Comment: You can not send headers after you've printed html. But as @SUTerliakov mentions, you've got a bigger problem.

Comment: If you, with access to the DB, don't know where the name is, how are we, with no access, suppose to know? Seems like schema should be rethought out anyway. The real issue like is that you should be using rewrite rules for this.